# Prepare string with regex for HTML tags management

Tags: regex

P/S: I am a PHP programmer.
Given:

```
div{3|5|6|9}[id = abc| class=image], a[id=link|class=out]
```

I want to use regex to generate a result as an array, e.g:

array(

```
  [div] => array(
                "3|5|6|9",
                "id = abc| class=image"
                )

  [a] => array(
                "",
                "id=link|class=out")
```

)

Would anyone please help?
Thank you a lot!

Comment: Does this have to be a regexp? I'd just process the string cand character by character and build the result as I went along...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a try with this:

```
$str='div{3|5|6|9}[id = abc| class=image], a[id=link|class=out]';

preg_match_all('/(\w+)(\{(.*?)\})?\[(.*?)\](?:, |$)?/', $str, $m);

$out = array($m[1][0] => array($m[3][0], $m[4][0]), $m[1][1] => array($m[3][1], $m[4][1]));

print_r($out);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [div] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3|5|6|9
            [1] => id = abc| class=image
        )

    [a] => Array
        (
            [0] =>
            [1] => id=link|class=out
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can guarantee that a comma will not exist between `{` and `}` and between `[` and `]`, you can first split the string by `,` and then use this regular expression:

```
/([a-z]+)(\{(.*?)\})?\[(.*?)\]/
```

The captured groups that you want are `$1`, `$3`, and `$4` (those back-reference numbers should match up if you use `preg_match_all`)

**Note:** I tested this out in Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match_all('/(\w+)(\{(.*?)\})?\[(.*?)\](?:, |$)?/', $str, $m);
```

I believe the above is fine to work unless another string like:

```
$str='div{3|5|6|9}[id = abc| class=image], a[id=link|class=out], br, ul';
```

the regex does not capture the br and ul.